# "invalid handle was passed to the function" on MoveNext when another process is sending many messages

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to create an application that oversees message queues as they are processing messages.

To snapshot the message queue, i wrote the following code:

```
        MessageEnumerator msgEnum = null;

        try
        {
            // some code that fetches q (the queue)
            msgEnum = q.GetMessageEnumerator2();

            while (msgEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                Message current = msgEnum.Current;
                Envelope msg = current.Body as Envelope;
                // do something with the message
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              // handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            if (msgEnum != null)
                msgEnum.Close();
        }
```

However, while another application is sending lots and lots of messages into the queue, i get the aforementioned exception.

I'm really confused as to why this is happening and what i need to do to make it work.

I also tried using `GetAllMessages` which resulted in the same exception.

Any help and/or explanations would be welcome.

edit:
the stack trace:

```
    Error message: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: An invalid handle was passed to the function. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: An invalid handle was passed to the function.
   at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.MoveNext(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Astea.AO.API.ControllerService.GetMessagesHeaders(String profileName, MessageQueueType queueType) in c:\Astea Alliance 11.0\Src\Framework\Astea.AO.API\Astea.AO.API.ControllerService\ControllerService.cs:line 170
   at SyncInvokeGetMessagesHeaders(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)).
Stack trace:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at APIConsoleWeb.Utils.Util.ReportError(String message) in c:\Astea Alliance 11.0\API.Controller\API.Controller\Utils\Util.cs:line 14
   at APIConsoleWeb.Controllers.QueueMessagesController.GetMessagesHeaders(String profileName, MessageQueueType queueType) in c:\Astea Alliance 11.0\API.Controller\API.Controller\Controllers\QueueMessagesController.cs:line 37
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionDescriptorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ExecuteAsync>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEndAsync[TResult](ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Func`1 execute, Action`2 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionDescriptorTracer.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionInvokerTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEndAsync[TResult](ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Func`1 execute, Action`2 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionInvokerTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.ExecuteAsyncCore(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<>c__DisplayClass3.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController.ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEndAsync[TResult](ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Func`1 execute, Action`2 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.RequestMessageHandlerTracer.<>n__FabricatedMethod6(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken )
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.RequestMessageHandlerTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<SendAsync>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEndAsync[TResult](ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Func`1 execute, Action`2 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.RequestMessageHandlerTracer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<>n__FabricatedMethod9(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken )
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(HttpContextBase contextBase)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest>b__0()
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(Func`1 taskFunc, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Comment: You are probably dealing with a *fire-hose* problem here.  Getting messages at a higher rate than you can process.  That makes this kind of code vulnerable to what else is going on in your program.  The loop never stops, constantly finding new messages.  That doesn't stop until you end your program.  Making `q` invalid and crashing the code.  Something like that.  Strongly avoid fire-and-forget threading, that while() loop needs another exit condition, it should stop when your program is about to end.

Comment: @HansPassant the program that executes this code is doing so synchronously; it will only stop when the while loop ends.. therefor - i see no other stop condition i could use; 
it does seems like you have a point there - if i run this code early in the populating program's life i do get results without an exception.

Comment: Document your question better, show the exception's stack trace.

Comment: good idea, posted.
i do notice `ReceiveCurrent` is being called - is `Current` doing that? should i try and peek instead somehow?

Comment: @HansPassant apologies - i posted the wrong trace. current edit reflects the real trace.

Comment: Hmm, ASP.NET.  I still like my original theory, there is a timeout built into ASP.NET that's going to abort code that doesn't completes a client request in a timely matter.  You'll need to put fire-hose protection into that while() loop so it doesn't endlessly loop.  Use time for example, nothing nice happens when it loops for more than a second.

Comment: @HansPassant tried limiting the loop to 900 miliseconds - no change. the trace said nothing about a timeout either (asp will inform). 
also, when i run this code without the second process running it will complete the loop without trouble even without limiting it time-wise; with it it crashes pretty much instantly.